# Pandas Panel Slicing - Improving Performance

Tags: python, pandas

All,

I'm currently using a panel in pandas to hold my data source. My program is a simple backtesting engine. It is only for personal amusement, however, I'm getting stuck in optimizing it.

The piece of code that is slowing down the entire application is the following:

```
def get_generator(self):
    first_n = 0
    last_n = len(self.data_source.major_axis)
    cur_n = 0
    indices = self.data_source.major_axis
    while cur_n < last_n:
        yield self.data_source.ix[:, indices[first_n:cur_n + 1], :]
        cur_n += 1
```

As you can see, I'm basically generating a new view in the world every moment in time and returning it. The indices are just dates.

This code is incredibly slow with the amount of data I'm trying to use.

Would you know how I can improve the speed of this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.data_source.ix[:, :cur_n, :]
```

is equivalent to

```
self.data_source.ix[:, indices[first_n:cur_n + 1], :]
```

but could be 2-3 times as fast:

```
In [105]: import pandas as pd    
In [106]: import numpy as np
In [107]: wp = pd.Panel(np.random.randn(2, 1000, 4))

In [108]: indices = wp.major_axis

In [109]: %timeit wp.ix[:, :499, :]
10000 loops, best of 3: 65.2 us per loop

In [110]: %timeit wp.ix[:, indices[0:500], :]
1000 loops, best of 3: 221 us per loop

In [114]: np.allclose(wp.ix[:, :499, :].values, wp.ix[:, indices[0:500], :].values)
Out[114]: True
```

`self.data_source.ix[:, :cur_n, :]` uses [basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/numpy/docs/numpy-docs/reference/arrays.indexing.rst/#arrays-indexing). It returns a *view* of the original panel. Be careful to note that modifying the view will also modify the original panel.

`indices[first_n:cur_n + 1]` is a subclass of NumPy's ndarray.  [Indexing with an ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/numpy/docs/numpy-docs/reference/arrays.indexing.rst/#advanced-indexing) returns a *copy*, not a view. Making copies of a large array is slower than returning a view, which is probably where the majority of the speed gain is coming from. However, sometimes you might need a copy -- such as when you want to modify the yielded subpanel without modifying the original panel.

---

Thanks to @Jeff for the additional idea of using transpose. On my machine it yields a significant improvement:

```
In [131]: wpt = wp.transpose(1,0,2)

In [132]: %timeit wpt.ix[:499]
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.5 us per loop

In [109]: %timeit wp.ix[:, :499, :]
10000 loops, best of 3: 65.2 us per loop
```

Comment: FYI, sometimes you can transpose and access faster (depended on your memory is aligned), in this case (about 10% boost): ``wpt = wp.transpose(1,0,2). %timeit wpt.ix[:499] : 78.7 us per loop, %timeit wp.ix[:,:499] : 87.6 us per loop``

Comment: With both modifications I was able to get the main loop from 160s to 3s. Amazing difference.
Thank you so much guys, it really made my app usable.

Comment: great. that is an amazing difference